# Use FFMPEG to convert MP4/AAC to MP3 without audio time getting shortened

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I've been struggling with extracting the audio from a couple of mp4 files I have. I have tried using all of the different answers posted previously on Stack Overflow, but each of them results in an mp3 file that's shorter than the original mp4.

If anyone has any insights as to what I'm doing wrong, that'd be greatly appreciated, or at the very least why it's not this simple to convert from mp4 to mp3.

I have tried copying the codec and using variable bitrate. The input video is 1:24:56, but the output audio is 1:24:46.

Command: `ffmpeg -i sample.mp4 -c:v copy -q:a 0 sample.mp3`

Output:

```bash
$ffmpeg -i sample.mp4 -c:v copy -q:a 0 sample.mp3

ffmpeg version 2023-01-09-git-13d04e30d7-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.1.0 (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libvpl --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      57. 43.100 / 57. 43.100
  libavcodec     59. 56.100 / 59. 56.100
  libavformat    59. 34.102 / 59. 34.102
  libavdevice    59.  8.101 / 59.  8.101
  libavfilter     8. 53.100 /  8. 53.100
  libswscale      6.  8.112 /  6.  8.112
  libswresample   4.  9.100 /  4.  9.100
  libpostproc    56.  7.100 / 56.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'sample.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 01:24:56.57, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 612 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 480 kb/s, 29.94 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (aac (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mp3, to 'sample.mp3':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    TSSE            : Lavf59.34.102
  Stream #0:0(und): Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc59.56.100 libmp3lame
size=   88336kB time=01:24:56.54 bitrate= 142.0kbits/s speed= 172x
video:0kB audio:88336kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000394%
```

Comment: Post your cmd line. Difference is about seconds, or a few samples?

Comment: Edited with the requested information! As you can see, the output gets shortened by several seconds, which scales as the video file grows larger.

Comment: Very bad. I can confirm, tested in Cubase and Pro Tools. Look at this screenshot, MP3 is stretched and out of sync compared to original audio. [Cubase](https://i.imgur.com/qVpbDw2.png)

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea why this may be the case. Do you?

Comment: Any news? I have the same issue and I cannot understand why this happens on Ubuntu and not on Mac